# How to convert UTC dates to user specified timezone in mongoose in find query or while retrieving

Tags: mongoose

We have a requirement where we need to convert dates stored in mongodb to the user specified timezone while doing a find query or retrieving it.

This is applicable to all the dates. We are using nodejs / mongoose.

I tried to use aggregation projection datetostring but it doesn't seem to take effect.

Can anyone share how to achieve it?

I tried below , which has no effect .Program is my Model.

```
Program.findById(req.params.programId,"-ae_config"/*, {"$expr": [{
    "$project": {
            date: { $dateToString: { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", date: "programStartDate", timezone: "America/New_York"} },
    }
}]}*/).populate('roles').exec(function (err, program) {
```

Comment: IMHO the database should only handle UTC, converting in other timezones is a front-end issue (so users can pick their time zone etc.).

Comment: @Alex is totally correct. Whatever you do, store all datetimes in UTC and handle your requirements by tweaking the search parameters accordingly. You have to have a single standard way to know all values are stored in order to have a single way to query across them.  UTC is absolutely your answer here.

Comment: we are storing in mongo DB in UTC format. I am working on middlelayer or API side in nodejs.. when I query from DB while passing data  to UI , we are trying to  to convert in user local timezone. e.g if the UTC date is  3.00 am UTC ,  if the logged on user  timezone is  EST , it should be shown as 10 pm EST

Comment: as I posted  I am trying to use datetostring aggregation  which doesnt seem to be working

Comment: Does not seem to be working? As in "throwing an error" perhaps? If you actually get an error then you need to actually say so within your question. "Not working" is not a specific enough statement. If it's something different to an "error" then you need to show that as well. But most likely it's because you simply do not have **MongoDB 3.6** just like the documentation page tells you is actually required to use the `"timezone"` option.

Comment: Besides "aggregation **pipeline stages**" are for use **only** within the `.aggregate()` command. If you want to "group by rounded date for the timezeone" then use `$group` with `.aggregate()`. The `$expr` documentation also says that "pipelines" ( like `$project`, `$group` etc ) **cannot** be used as an "expression". Only "expression" operators ( `$size`, `$setIsSubset` etc ) can be used within `$expr`.

Comment: @NeilLunn my mongo version is 3.6.3. When I say it doesnt work , it doesnt seem to take effect. IT is not throwing any error.. But I was expecting  in above example programStartDate would be converted to "america new/ york" timezone which is not happening.

Comment: You cannot use `$project` in a `find()`. I already said that.

Comment: Also if I am using it wrongly , how will this typically be done in mongoose / mongo DB ?  I want to convert UTC dates to local time timezone provided by user at the time of retrival